# ASP.NET - Missing ticket.UserData() in AuthenticateRequest(), old working code installed on new server

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I've just migrated an old (ASP.NET 2.0) web site to a new server. The application has been maintained for about 8 year (upgraded to ASP.NET 4) and was working fine on the old server. It's also working fine on my development computer.

I've been searching for an answer most of this week, tried a few options but I still cannot figure this one out. Any help/pointer would be appreciated.

Below is the most pertinent snippets of running code.

TIA, Raymond

```
Shared Function LogMeIn(ByVal p As Page, ByVal sUserName As String, ByVal sPassword As     String, ByVal bPersists As Boolean, ByVal lblMessage As Label) As Integer
    Try
        'get the login dataset
        Dim dsLogin As DataSet = GetUserDataSetByUserName(sUserName)

        If dsLogin.Tables(0).Rows.Count = 1 Then

            FormsAuthentication.Initialize()

            Dim sGoodPassword As String = dsLogin.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Password").ToString
            Dim sRole As String = dsLogin.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Roles").ToString

            'check password
            If sPassword = sGoodPassword Then
                Dim ticket As New FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, _
                                                            sUserName, _
                                                            DateTime.Now, _
                                                            DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60 * 480), _
                                                            bPersists, sRole, _
                                                               FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath)

                Dim hash As String = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket)
                Dim cookie As New HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hash)

                If ticket.IsPersistent Then cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(15)

                cookie.HttpOnly = True

                p.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie)

                Dim sReturnUrl As String = "..." 'removed for clarity

                p.Response.Redirect(sReturnUrl, True)

            Else
                lblMessage.Text = "Incorrect Password"
                Return 1
            End If
        Else
            '... 'removed for clarity
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        '... 'removed for clarity
    End Try

End Function


Sub Application_AuthenticateRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    ' Fires upon attempting to authenticate the use
    If Not (HttpContext.Current.User Is Nothing) Then

        Dim gpUser As GenericPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User


        If gpUser.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
            If TypeOf gpUser.Identity Is FormsIdentity Then

                Dim fi As FormsIdentity = CType(gpUser.Identity, FormsIdentity)

                Dim ticket As FormsAuthenticationTicket = fi.Ticket
                Dim sRoles As String()
                Dim i As Integer

                sRoles = ticket.UserData.Split(",")
                For i = 0 To sRoles.Length - 1
                    sRoles(i) = Trim(sRoles(i))
                Next

                HttpContext.Current.User = New GenericPrincipal(fi, sRoles)

            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to the fact that I'm using an Access database and that the site was originally build on ASP.NET 1.0. The solution was to implement custom Membership and Role providers.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27955/Developing-custom-ASP-NET-Membership-and-Role-prov